# Vertically align nested DIVs using CSS

Tags: html, css

Look at at

http://jsfiddle.net/user0815/ZU9bT/

I want that the two DIV containing an image each should be vertically aligned within the outer DIV.

I tried the common tricks using

```
display: table-cell
vertical-align: center
```

but no love.

Any idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZU9bT/1/ is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, I mean they should be vertically aligned. The inner boxes should be place side by side (that's why they are using float: left;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `vertical-align: middle` and *not* `vertical-align: center`.

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZU9bT/2/

---

**Updated demo** with `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZU9bT/3/

Comment: Nope, the outer height of the box is 200px. So #box1 (height 100px) should be placed with a margin of 50px from the top of the outer box and #box1 (height 150px) with 25px from top. I do not want so specify individual top/margin for #box1|box2.

Comment: Ok, let me see. But note that it is `middle` and not `center` for `vertical-align`