# Moving Nested Div to bottom corner with CSS

Tags: css

i searched on here and found one solution but doesnt seem to answer what im looking for

([Vertically align nested DIVs using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081835/vertically-align-nested-divs-using-css))

My question is when you have 2 divs with one nested in the other div, by default the inner div will be on the top left, how would i put this on the bottom right corner? Thanks!

Comment: I don't find a reason why someone made a negative vote to this question. I find the question interesting , reasonable as well as informative. + 1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

add to the parent `position: relative;`

and to the nested div

```
position: absolute;
right:0px
bottom 0px;
```

Comment: Right said, worked perfectly. Make sure the height of the parent div is specified explicitly with css.

Answer (score 0):

```
.outerDiv{
    position:relative;
}

.innerDiv{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```